# mongo check if date is greater than current date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am checking whether my `expiry` date is greater than `current` `date`, but the code seems to fail.

In my database, expiry is stored like this.

```
"expiry" : ISODate("2015-10-03T16:49:08.000Z"),
```

I am comparing this field like this below : `expiry: { $gt: Date.now() }`, but i am not getting the `user` object.

The `token` is passed correctly and the `expiry:` `{ '$gt': 1443892755342 }` also gets the `timestamp`.

```
User.findOne({ token: req.params.token, expiry: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
            console.log("first", user);
            if (err) {
                res.status(403).json({
                    "status": "200",
                    "data": 'Failed'
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                "status": "200",
                "data": user
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you try with new Date()

Comment: @RohitJain: Same result...

Comment: What is a current system date ?

Comment: Its current date 10/04/2015

Comment: Then how it will give the output try $lt operator

Comment: The expiry field has a date which is greater than the current date with a hour... new Date() + 360000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91260/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-shane).